# Solaris 11: two manifest for service! I want one

Tags: solaris, smf

I import a rc.local become a SVC service

Procedure work but..
I see two manifest!

```
svcs -l  svc:/site/rclocal:default
fmri         svc:/site/rclocal:default
name         Run-once service
enabled      true
state        online
next_state   none
state_time   17 dicembre 2017 02:02:50 CET
logfile      /var/svc/log/site-rclocal:default.log
restarter    svc:/system/svc/restarter:default
manifest     /root/rc.local.xml
manifest     /lib/svc/manifest/system/rc.local.xml
dependency   require_all/none svc:/system/filesystem/local:default (online)
```

Question is: how to delete one manifest?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: did you run `svccfg import /lib/svc/manifest/system/rc.local.xml` ?

Comment: If that doesn't work my hunch is you imported the service from your `/root/` directory and that is why you have two manifests.  You may need to delete the service and re-import from the correct location.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/solaris-smf-manifest-wp-167902.pdf

Comment: I made it..but return this error  The manifest being imported is from a standard location and should be imported with the  command : svcadm restart svc:/system/manifest-import I did the command,but service not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old one but...

1. `mv /lib/svc/manifest/system/rc.local.xml` to someplace
2. `svcadm restart svc:/system/manifest-import`
3. check that rclocal is gone:  `svcs -l  rclocal`
4. mv `rc.local.xml` back to the `/lib/svc/manifest/system/rc.local.xml`, but better to the `/lib/svc/manifest/site/`
5. `svcadm restart svc:/system/manifest-import`
6. check again: `svcs -l   rclocal`